# Macbook Pro doesn't switch on unless I take off its battery (mid 2010)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

I changed the battery of my Macbook Pro mid 2010 and it worked all fine for some time.

Then I stopped using the computer for a while (around 1 year or a year and a half) and now the computer won't switch on unless I open it and I remove the battery.

I've done that, removed the battery, switch it on and reset the SMC and the NVRAM or PRAM.
Then plugged the battery on again and nothing. Not switching on again.

I also tried leaving the computer charging the battery for about 5 hours. Nothing.

If the battery is wrong, why won't it switch on when still plugged into the network via magsafe?

I would rather not buy another battery because they are about $50 and this computer is 11 years old. Trying to look for another solution if possible as I won't be using this computer that much anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Li-ion batteries do not respond well to being allowed to run *absolutely* flat. If they drop below approx 2% power, a firmware switch will kick in & not allow then to be recharged.
A professional *may* be able to circumvent this, but it is potentially hazardous & should not be attempted by the user.

Your choices are…

1. Leave it on charge for another day & see if it's actually charging, albeit slowly.
2. Take it to a repair shop & see if they can 'reboot' the battery.
3. If it will run without the battery, then try that. It will throttle down & will probably crash hard if you stress the CPU or GPU, as the charger alone is not powerful enough to run the computer under high load - that's what the battery is for.
4. ..of course… buy a new battery.